# Why jekyll not showing comments?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the code:

```html
{% for comment in site.data.comments | where: "slug", page.slug %}
<div class="comment">
<div class="meta">
<p class="name">
{% if comment.email %}
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ comment.email }}?d=mm&s=60" alt="{{ comment.name| escape }}">
{% else %}
<img src="/blog/lib/img/avatar.jpg" alt="{{ comment.name | escape }}">
{% endif %} Od: {{ comment.name | strip_html }} * {{ comment.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y, %H:%M" }}</p>
</div>
<p class="message">{{ comment.message | strip_html | markdownify | smartify }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which should replace the comment placed in `data/comments/postid/commentid.yml` with a comment in html but the result looks like this:

```html
<div class="comment"> 
<div class="meta"> 
<p class="name"> 

<img src="/blog/lib/img/avatar.jpg" alt=""> 
 From:   * </p> 
</div> 
<p class="message"></p> 
</div>
```

I just know there's something wrong with the values for `comment` but I don't know how to fix it.

And here is a sample comment in the file `.yml`

```
_id: a39a2830-4ab0-11ea-a10f-77385622cc26
name: Igor Kowalczyk
email: 28a451314d9295e9bcce66c293bd20ed
message: Testowy Komentarz
date: '2020-02-08T20:21:51.037Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly understanding how you get all datas, but one thing is sure is that you need to assign and then loop :

```
{% assign comments = site.data.comments | where: "slug", page.slug %}
{% for comment in comments %}
...
```

**Edit**:

Watching your comments and associated code, it seems that you need to configure staticman to create comments in a specific folder for each post.

In **staticman.yml**, add

```
path : "_data/comments/{options.slug}"
```

Then, you can select post related comments with `{% assign comments = site.data.comments[page.slug] %}`.

Code from [Minimal Mistakes](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/102924ff940d5b7f03493bb70aedcbad2d99286f/_includes/comments.html#L15) can be inspiring.

Comment: I found something like this: https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/102924ff940d5b7f03493bb70aedcbad2d99286f/_includes/comments.html#L20 but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is my repository if you want more information for the code: https://github.com/IgorKowalczyk/blog

Comment: I'm add this to my repo (https://github.com/IgorKowalczyk/blog) but this is not work. (See in the repo `_includes` and `layouts`, maybe i'm doing this wrong.